# Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ -- error: object 'glue_' not found

Tags: r, tidyverse

Does anyone know why I'm getting the following message when I load tidyverse in a new session. (I have the most recent version of tidyverse, RStudio, and R.)

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’:  .onAttach
> failed in attachNamespace() for 'tidyverse', details:   call:
> glue(str, .envir = .envir, .transformer = transformer, .cli = TRUE,
> error: object 'glue_' not found

I also have the most recent version of the glue package installed.